# scala spring web mvc

Tags: scala, spring-mvc

I have a scala controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(Array("/welcome"))
class HelloController{

  @RequestMapping{val method = Array(RequestMethod.GET)}
  def printWelcome(model: ModelMap) = {
    println("IN: printWelcome(..)")
    val greeting = new GreetingBean("Yo!", "Adam")
    model.addAttribute("message", greeting);
    "secure" // sends to the /jsf/secure.xhtml page
  }

  @RequestMapping{val value = Array("/greeting"), val method = Array(RequestMethod.GET)}
  def greeting(model: ModelMap) = {
    println("IN: greeting(..)")
    val greeting = new GreetingBean("Greetings", "Davies")
    model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
    "greeting"; // sends to the /jsf/greeting.xhtml page
  }
}
```

When i call `http://localhost:8080/jsf-spring-guice/welcome` the message `IN: printWelcome(..)` is displayed in the console and the correct page is navigated to.

when I call `http://localhost:8080/jsf-spring-guice/welcome/greeting` I get a `404` error.

I have tried specifying the @RequestMapping on the greetings method in different ways:

```
@RequestMapping{val value = Array("greeting"), val method = Array(RequestMethod.GET)}
@RequestMapping{val value = Array("/greeting")}
@RequestMapping(Array("/greeting"))
@RequestMapping(Array("/greeting"), Array(RequestMethod.GET))
```

and de-compiled the generated class which always looks fine. But I always get OK with welcome and always 202 with /welcome/greeting

The decompiled Scala class has this:

```
@RequestMapping({"/welcome"})
```

and this:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/greeting"}, method={org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET})
```

I can't see any reason why this should not be working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this a correct way of specifying annotation..shouldn't it be:`@RequestMapping(value = Array("/greeting"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))`

Comment: HelloController.scala:31: error: not found: value method
  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/greeting"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
                                              ^

Answer (score 0):

Haven't check it and compile, but `@RequestMapping` annotation for `printWelcome` method should also have specified value, even if it is empty ("").

The specified value acts as a filter and that's likely the cause of the problem.

Comment: The `printWelcome` method is the one that works. Trying it now in pure Java. Will post results

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
...But couldn't find the answer on Spring documentation.

Situation was I had in `web.xml`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This meant that the mapping '@RequestMapping(Array("/welcome"))' had no effect and any request to `http://localhost:8080/jsf-spring-guice/welcome` would be processed by method marked with `@RequestMapping{val method = Array(RequestMethod.GET)}`. A kind of default `get`.

The clue was that when I entered `http://localhost:8080/jsf-spring-guice/welcome/welcome/greeting/` the method marked with `@RequestMapping{val value = Array("/greeting"), val method = Array(RequestMethod.GET)}` was called. At this point it was clear that the double `welcome` meant something was amiss.

So basically, the `url-pattern` acts as a pre-fix to URL patters (we all know that), but the catch is that the controller with a simple GET method will act as a default.

**Note to self** do not use controller with same request mapping as `url-pattern`